# Retrieve first matching object in array by boolean

Tags: javascript, find, boolean

How do I retrieve the first object with `free:true` in the array below without looping through it myself? Is there a one-liner?

```
var leftCoords = [{x: 60, y: 192, free: false}, {x: 15, y: 20, free: false}, {x: 435, y: 60, free: true}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Array `find` method.

```js
var leftCoords = [{x: 60, y: 192, free: false}, {x: 15, y: 20, free: false}, {x: 435, y: 60, free: true}];

// Find it
const found = leftCoords.find(el => el.free);
console.log(found);

// Now we can set it to false
found.free = false;
console.log(leftCoords);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I actually forgot that there was a second part to my question. I need to change the value of free in the found object so `free: true` becomes `free: false`. That can't be done with `find`, right?

Comment: Updated. We can just directly set free to `false`.

Comment: Wow, I did not know the reference worked backwards like that! Thanks alot!

Comment: Yeah, it found the object and is still pointing to the same object in memory.